# What is the current standpoint on artificial sweeteners?

Tags: sweeteners

I found this: [Are artificial sweeteners safe?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/46/are-artificial-sweeteners-safe)

But I heard that there were studies/was a study released recently which were against artificial sweeteners. I can't really find them/it.

Have you heard anything new about this topic or that 2015 post mentioned above is actual?

Comment: I have no sources to offer you.  I have spoken with 2 different RDs (registered dietitians) and other colleagues about it, and the opinions are still mixed. Some cited poor quality of the studies against it.  I would love to see a good answer to this question from someone with more expertise than I have!